# Make reactive joins in Meteor+ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

Have been struggling with this for really long; with my Meteor+ReactJS app, I want to have a reactive join between the MainCollection and the SubCollection. And the PublishComposite might just be what I need. However, when the SubCollection is updated, this is not reactive!

does anyone know how to make a reactive server-side join with meteor+react?

**server code**

```
import { publishComposite } from 'meteor/reywood:publish-composite';
Meteor.MainCollection('maincollection.pub.all', {
  find: function () {
    return MainCollection.find();
  },
  children: [
    {
      find: function (doc) {
        return SubCollection.find(
          { mainCollectionId: doc._id },
          {
            sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: 1,
            fields: {
              completedAt: 1,
              mainCollectionId: 1,
            }
          })
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

**client container**

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  let mainCollectionSub = Meteor.subscribe('maincollection.pub.all');
  options = {
    transform: function (doc) {
      doc.subcollection = SubCollection.findOne({
        mainCollectionId: doc._id }, ).fetch();
      return doc;
    }
  }
    var maincollection = MainCollection.find({}, options).fetch();
  return {
    maincollection: MainCollection.find({}, options).fetch(),
  }
}, MainCollectionView);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `SubCollection.findOne()` is not reactive before it's used inside `transform` handler rather than in the first argument of `createContainer`. Try this:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  let mainCollectionSub = Meteor.subscribe('maincollection.pub.all');
  options = {
    transform: function (doc) {
      doc.getSubCollection = function () {
        return SubCollection.findOne({
          mainCollectionId: this._id,
        });
      };
      return doc;
    }
  }
  return {
    maincollection: MainCollection.find({}, options).fetch(),
    subcollections: SubCollection.find().fetch(),
  };
}, MainCollectionView);
```

Then you can call `doc.getSubCollection()` which is reactive data source for the related subcollection.